# Поиск элемента в сегменте(слайсе) golang

Tags: golang, поиск

В сегменте строк надо найти элемент - строку. Я не нашел встроенного метода для этого, мне что самому писать его придётся? Скорее всего ответ будет да, поэтому следующий вопрос: может есть какая-то библиотека, которая делает из сырого golang , нормальный яп.
Или может я какую-то тонкую философию не понимаю?

Comment: Pak Uula вся надежда на вас

Comment: Я полагаю, речь о slice? Для работы со слайсами есть пакет [`golang.org/x/exp/slices`](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/exp/slices). В этом пакете есть функция линейного поиска `Index`, есть функции сортировки и бинарного поиска.